# reorder datatable rows with a specific sequence of values

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a datatable that looks like this:

```
IDDOC   DOCNAME
1       mydoc1
153     mydoc2
98      mydoc3  
1327    mydoc4
241     mydoc5
```

I would like to find a way to reorder the rows in that datatable by basing on a specific sequence of ID

For example, with a sequence like this : 1327,98,1 the expected output would be :

```
IDDOC   DOCNAME
1327    mydoc4
98      mydoc3  
1       mydoc1
153     mydoc2 (not in my sequence so this row comes at the end)
241     mydoc5 (not in my sequence so this row comes at the end)
```

I was thinking about creating a new empty database and adding the row with the IDDOC coming first, then second, then third in the sequence, then finally all the rows not present in my sequence but i was wondering if something cleaner already existed.
Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: What if there is only a row 1327, should it be first even if the other two are missing?

Comment: If there is just one row in the datatable. I won't reorder anything !

Comment: No, i meant what if there are multiple rows but only one with 1327 id and none with 98 and 1. Should the 1327 still come first or should it remain unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("IDDOC") == 1327 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<int>("IDDOC") == 98 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<int>("IDDOC") == 1 ? 0 : 1)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want a dynamic list of id's and the `DataTable` should be ordered by this sequence:

```
List<int> docIdSequence = new List<int>{ 1327, 98, 1 };

dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => { 
        int ix = docIdSequence.IndexOf(r.Field<int>("IDDOC"));
        return ix >= 0 ? ix : int.MaxValue;
    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that `CopyToDataTable` throws an exception if there are no input `DataRows`. So you have to check if `dt.Rows.Count > 0` before you use above code.

Comment: I like your idea. Thank you !